# Why does implicit derivative change after division? (For $\sec(x)+\tan(y) = \sec(x)*\tan(y))$)

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

If I take the implicit derivative without dividing, I get the solution $\frac{dy}{dx} = (\sec(x) \tan(x) \cos(y)) \frac{\cos(y)-\sin(y))}{\sec(x)-1}$.

[image: Main solution]

If I divide both sides by $\sec(x) \tan(y)$, I get $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\sin(x) (\sin y)^2$.

This solution does additionally assume $y$ is not equal to $k \pi$.

For the second solution, I did separation of variables to get $y=-\arctan(\sec(x))$. When this is plugged back in to the original equation, we get $-(\sec(x))^2=0$, which is impossible, apparently disproving this whole method.

What is going on? Why are the implicit derivatives different?

[image: "Alternative" solution]

Comment: How did you got $y=−\arctan(\sec(x))$. That's obiously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

These two different expressions for the derivative are equivalent when $x$ and $y$ satisfy
$$
\sec(x) + \tan(y) = \sec(x)\tan(y).
$$
Let us prove that. Suposing that
$$
\sec(x) + \tan(y) = \sec(x)\tan(y),
$$
if we multiply by $\cos(x)\cos(y)$ on both sides, we get
$$
\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x) = \sin(y),
$$
so

> $\cos(y)-\sin(y) = -\sin(y)\cos(x)$,

and

> $\tan(y)=\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(x)}.$

Keep these two identities in mind.

Begining with the first equation you got for the derivative:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sec(x)\tan(x)\cos(y)(\cos(y)-sin(y))}{\sec(x)-1} = \frac{\sec(x)\tan(x)\cos(y)(\cos(y)-\sin(y))}{\sec(x)-1}\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}
=\frac{\tan(x)\cos(y)(\cos(y)-\sin(y))}{1-\cos(x)}
$$
Substituing both the identities we stated at the begining,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =\tan(x)\cos(y)(-\sin(y)\cos(x))\tan(y) = -\sin(x)\sin^2(y),
$$
as we wished.